# Android application background colour 

Tags: android

I have my main.xml up and in the XML code I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/logo" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="116dp"></ImageView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Administration 0.0.1" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But when I run the app in an emulator, the default theme still shows with the black background. I can't figure out why it's doing this.

Any ideas?

Comment: it should work. Could you post the code around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What background color are you expecting? It shows up correctly for me if you're expecting white. This is what the screen looks like (I have substituted your image with the android icon)

[image: My Screen]

Does your onCreate() look like this -

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

Comment: Hi - No, it looks white for me too in the design view but when I run it in the emulator it goes back to black. Yes my onCreate() looks like that too...

Comment: It looked white for me on the emulator as well as a device. What emulator are you using? What version of Android are you using?